# not enough arguments to mouseEvent.initMouseEvent

Tags: javascript

The following JS code works on Safari properly :

```
var a = $('.shell a')[0];
var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evObj.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window);
a.dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

However, this line

```
evObj.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window);
```

gives me the following error in Firefox:

```
TypeError: Not enough arguments to MouseEvent.initMouseEvent.
```

What should I use for multi-browser compatibility?

Comment: That's the old way. The new way is much simpler: `evObj = new Event('click');` -- **All** browsers? Goodluck with that. `click` is simple though. Just do `domElement.click()`.

Comment: @Rudie Do you mean `jQueryElement.click()`?

Comment: No, I mean the native `domElement.click()`. Try it in the console: `document.querySelector('a').click()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see on [MDN's `initEvent` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initEvent), using events like that is deprecated. "Use event constructors instead":

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

In your case:

```
var evObj = new Event('click');
a.dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

But `click` events are much simpler! Native DOM has a `click()` method for all elements, so you can do this:

```
a.click();
```

That's it.

If you want to trigger custom events or events like `mouseover`, you can still use the (new) event dispatch system: `new Event('mouseover')` etc